# Why does this if statement work on an emulator but not on an actual device

Tags: android, multithreading

I want to have a timer dialog that will start at 0 and every 5 seconds make a sound. It works perfectly on an emulator for a Nexus S API 22, but does not work on my HTC One M8 API 21 phone. The log message is logged and the sound is heard on the emulator, but neither happen on my actual phone, so I don't think it's a sound issue.

```
 private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;

        updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;

        int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
        int mins = secs / 60;
        secs = secs % 60;
        int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);

        if(secs > 0 && ((secs%5) == 0) && milliseconds == 0){
            Log.d("BEEP", "beep");
            tg.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_PROP_BEEP);
        }

        timerValue.setText("" + mins + ":"
                + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"
                + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
        customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
    }
};
```

here is also the onCreate and variable names for reference.

```
public class TimerDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener{    

private TextView timerValue;

private long startTime = 0L;

private Handler customHandler = new Handler();

long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
long timeSwapBuff = 0L;
long updatedTime = 0L;

ToneGenerator tg;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_timer,null);

    tg = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, 100);

    timerValue = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.timerText);
    startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);



    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setView(v)
            .setMessage("")
            .setCancelable(true)
            .setNegativeButton("Continue with instructions",this)
            .create();
}

....

}
```

Comment: Why postDelayed() with a value of 0? This does not make sense.

Comment: I want to actually update the clock so the time progression is shown.

Comment: You should probably use a non-zero delay to avoid burning up the CPU. Updating the timer display every 100ms should be more than enough.

Comment: I see.. I ended up doing similar to what Kasra suggested below, but I separated timing and sound into different Runnables using the same Handler. It works but is this bad practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this snippet:

```
    if(secs > 0 && ((secs%5) == 0) && milliseconds == 0){
        Log.d("BEEP", "beep");
        tg.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_PROP_BEEP);
    }
```

you are counting on `milliseconds` to be be 0 in order for the beep to sound. This is not a reliable assumption -- and it's a very bad practice of coding. If you want to beep every 5 sec, change your `Runnable` to this:

```
private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
    timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;

    updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;

    int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
    int mins = secs / 60;
    secs = secs % 60;
    int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);

    // if(secs > 0 && ((secs%5) == 0) && milliseconds == 0){  // <<<<<<<<<
    Log.d("BEEP", "beep");
    tg.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_PROP_BEEP);
    // }  // <<<<<<<<<

    timerValue.setText("" + mins + ":"
            + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"
            + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
    customHandler.postDelayed(this, 5000);  // <<<<<<<<<
   }
};
```

Comment: Is it not reliable because it is a sensitive time frame? If I were to do it the way you have then the clock would only update every 5 seconds, which isn't exactly what I want.

Comment: You can have another handler that updates the clock constantly. But it should be a another handler. And it is not reliable because you cannot guarantee that the timer always hit 5.000 sec.  It might hit 4.991 then it hits 5.002. This way you will miss the second 5...

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant by sensitive time frame. Why separate handlers and not just separate runnables doing different things on the same handler?